# How to show webapp's header bar on top of the external websites?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, toolbar, browser-extension

Let's suppose the webapp has list of external URLs. User clicks one of those URLs and goes to another website. How do I show the first webapp's header on top of the other websites?

http://www.stumbleupon.com/

These guys use iframe for this purpose, but if I will try to add a page from Pinterest, for example, then I will get only the Stumbleupon's header and blank body because `x-frame-options` of pinterest is set to `sameorigin`.

Comment: You can't achieve that if they don't allow cross origin.

Comment: Thank you, Buzinas! That's why I've asked it here) I need all possible alternatives - may be browser extensions will help me in this case may be some other stuff?

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge there is no way to put your own app's header above another site's content without using an iframe, and without an extension there is no way to bypass the same origin rule.

If you create a Chrome extension, you should be able to get it to request cross-origin permissions, and then your code should be allowed to embed previously unembeddable iframes.

From the [Chrome docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr):

> By adding hosts or host match patterns (or both) to the permissions section of the manifest file, the extension can request access to remote servers outside of its origin.
>
> ```
> {       
>    "name": "My extension",
>    ...
>    "permissions": [
>      "http://www.google.com/"
>    ],
>    ...
>  }
> ```

So you should be able to just add the pattern `*` to request CORS permissions on all sites for your Chrome extension. The `permissions` section is designed for AJAX requests so I'm not 100% sure this approach works with iframes, but I would give it a shot.

From my cursory research it looks like you might not be able to request cross-origin permissions with Firefox extensions, unfortunately, so it would be Chrome only.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Curl instead:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/Header");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$header = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

And the output would be `$header`, I believe this will be much faster and efficient for what your trying to do.